# How to sort string with numbers in it numerically?

Tags: kotlin, sorting, collections, natural-sort

So I am getting some json data and putting it inside of a Mutable List. I have a class with id, listId, and name inside of it. Im trying to sort the output of the list by listId which are just integers and then also the name which has a format of "Item 123". Im doing the following

```
val sortedList = data.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.listId }, { it.name }))
```

This sorts the listId correctly but the names is sorted alphabetically so the numbers go 1, 13, 2, 3. How am I able to sort both the categories but make the "name" also be sorted numerically?

Comment: Are _all_ the names numbers? If so why don't you make the `name` property an `Int` type ? If not, should a number be sorted before or after a non-number?

Comment: @Sweeper all the names are strings that have the word "item" followed by a space and then a number. I cant make it into a int because sometimes the names are empty and those need to be removed. I dont think it matters before or after as the string is always the same.

Comment: @Jaakko you can filter out elements with the empty name by `List.filter()` or `List.filterNot()` before sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
val sortedList = data.sortedWith(compareBy(
    { it.listId },
    { it.name.substring(0, it.name.indexOf(' ')) },
    { it.name.substring(it.name.indexOf(' ') + 1).toInt() }
))
```

will work but it is not computationally efficient because it will call `String.indexOf()` many times.

If you have a very long list, you should consider making another list whose each item has `String` and `Int` names.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**stringtoSort = "you5", "how3", "hello1", "are4", "world2"//**

```
class Test(val title:String) {   override fun toString(): String {
    return "$title"   } }



fun extractInt(s: Test): Int {
    val num = s.title.replace("\\D".toRegex(), "")
    // return 0 if no digits found
    return if (num.isEmpty()) 0 else Integer.parseInt(num) }fun main() {    // var sortData = null   val list= listOf<Test>(Test("you5"), Test("how3"), Test("hello1"), Test("are4"), Test("world2")) var sortData = list.sortedWith( object : Comparator<Test> { override fun compare(o1: Test, o2: Test): Int {
    return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2) } }

)

    println(sortData ) }
```